# meta data not decoding PHP

Tags: php, encoding, meta-tags, decoding, utf

The meta description for this link: http://www.mercurynews.com/samesexmarriage/ci_17794445?source=most_viewed&nclick_check=1

Is returning a strange character instead of a quote.

```
The federal judge who struck down Californias gay marriage ban has confirmed that hes gay. Chief U.
```

I am using `strip_tags(html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($description,  ENT_NOQUOTES), ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8"));`

What do? The weird character appears in place of a quote in the word "California's" and "He's"

Answer (score 1):

The site is encoding the HTML entities incorrectly. Those apostrophes in the source should be encoded as `&#x27;` — the hexadecimal number entity for the apostrophe (decimal number 39). They are using `&#27;`, which is the decimal number entity for the ASCII "Escape" character.

You can cover for their mistake pretty easily by adding a `str_replace` call:

```
$description = str_replace('&#27;', "'", $description);
$description = strip_tags(html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($description, ENT_NOQUOTES), ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

[Reference for ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/)